# FFMPEG - Convert MP3 and JPEG to MP4, different JPEG to every MP3

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, mp3

I want to convert every MP3 with different JPEGs and output an MP4.

1. mp3 and 1.jpg = 1.mp4
2. mp3 and 2.jpg = 2.mp4
3. mp3 and 3.jpg = 3.mp4 etc

How can I make code to get this right?

I use a batchfile

```
@echo off
mkdir converted
for %%a in ("*.mp3") do ffmpeg  -i "%%a" -loop 1 -i image1.jpg -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -shortest "converted\%%~na.mp4"
pause
```

Comment: Are the images sequenced?  image001.jpg  image002.jpg  image003.jpg....

Comment: yes, all immages is sequenced

Comment: somebody help??

Answer (score 1):

Something like this: Updated.....

```
@echo off

for %%a in (*.mp3) do call :CreateVideo "%%~a"

pause
exit

:CreateVideo
set /a Counter+=1
set CounterZero=000%Counter%
set CounterZero=%CounterZero:~-3%
ffmpeg -loop 1 -y -i "image%CounterZero%.jpg" -i "%~1" -shortest -acodec copy -vcodec libx264 "%~n1.mp4"
goto :EOF
```

Comment: This works,!! THANKS BUT


 its possible to make smth like this??


NamesongXXX.mp3 and 1.jpg = NamesongXXX.mp4
NamesongYYY.mp3 and 2.jpg = NamesongYYY.mp4
NamesongZZZ.mp3 and 3.jpg = NamesongZZZ.mp3.mp4

Comment: I thought you would this to be like this: NameSong1.mp3 + image1.jpg = Converted_NameSong.mp4

Comment: Just remove the Converted_ form the code....

Comment: Converted it means it will be in new folder named "Converted"

But your script means that I have to change name of picture to name of song, otherwise it will not work, but I want use just random names of  sequenced pictures, do you understand? :)

Comment: Ah ok, from your question it looked like mp3 and images had the same name except for file extension of course: 1.mp3 and 1.jpg = 1.mp4 | 2.mp3 and 2.jpg = 2.mp4 | 3.mp3 and 3.jpg = 3.mp4 etc

Comment: yeah, thats was example what I need, but I need liitle modifited this code and will be perfect, 
can u do that?

Comment: So are the images sequenced?

Comment: yes, images is sequenced

Comment: What is the name of the sequenced Images ? And where does the sequence start:? Do you have at least 1 image for each mp3? image001.jpg - image203.jpg

Comment: I have at least 1 image for 1 mp3
Name of pictures is image001.jpg, image002.jpg etc

Comment: Are the images in the same folder as the mp3 or not?

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: 1) The [ffmpeg image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) can accept sequences: `-i image%03d.jpg` (or  `-i image%%03d.jpg` in a bat file). 2) You need `-vf format=yuv420p` or most players wont like the video. 3) If output duration isn't right see [My ffmpeg output always add extra 30s of silence at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55804507/) 4) Many players don't like MP3 in MP4, so change `-acodec copy` to `-acodec aac`. 5) If this is for YouTube ignore #2 and #4.

Comment: `@echo off
mkdir converted
for %%a in ("*.mp3") do ffmpeg  -i "%%a" -loop 1 -i image%%03d.jpg -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -shortest "converted\%%~na.mp4"
pause`

this works but 1 picture = 1 frame
I want 1 picture on whole 1 song :) can u help?

Comment: Did my updated answer work?

Comment: It not work cause it cant find name mp3, I think '%%a' can't remebmer name mp3 from first part code

Comment: Can you try again...

Comment: Now it works!@!!!! THANKS MAN u are THE BOSS